# Displaying 1XXs and 3XXs in AWS CloudWatch Metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Is it possible to display `1XXs(Count)` and `3XXs(Count)` in AWS Load Balancer CloudWatch metrics?

The reason I want to know them is because I found that `Sum Requests (Count)` is higher than `Sum HTTP 5XXs (Count) + Sum ELB 5XXs (Count) + Sum HTTP 4XXs (Count) + Sum HTTP 2XXs (Count) + Sum ELB 4XXs (Count)`.

I want to know what the rest of the requests (I mean `Sum Requests` - (`Sum HTTP 5XXs + Sum ELB 5XXs + Sum HTTP 4XXs + Sum HTTP 2XXs + Sum ELB 4XXs`)) are.

Comment: HTTPCode_Backend_3XX metric will give you number of 3xx coming from the service. I'm not sure about 1xx.

Comment: Also, are you maybe looking at SampleCount stat? Try with Sum stat.